# ¿Como agrego gemas a Ruby de forma local sin internet?

Tags: rubygems

Hola soy nuevo en esta página y también en esto de la programación, por motivos casi inexplicables me inicié con Ruby (no ese Ruby On Rails) y leí sobre que se pueden agragar librerías y todo lo demás....
Pues quisiera saber cómo instalarlas, al escribir en CMD "gem install Arcadia" (por ejemplo) la busca y descarga desde internet, pero la PC (Windows 7 por cierto) no dispone de una conexión a la red por lo que da un error... Entonces quisiera saber cómo las instalo si ya descargué algunas (shoes, qbindings, GTK3..) desde otro lugar y son archivos con extensión .GEM
Ruby versión 2.3.3
Gem versión 2.5.2
Necesito ayuda sobre esto por favor.... si no se puede pues quizás cambie de lenguaje (¿Python?) o siga con Ruby tratando de aprender pues me resulta NO TAN DIFÍCIL.

Answer (score 0):

La única forma de obtener las librerías es con una conexión a Internet, pero puedes usar otra PC que este conectada a internet y que tenga Ruby instalada, entonces utilizas el **comando**:

```
gem install -i tmp *librería* -v *version*
```

Luego te mueves a la carpeta tmp del sistema, buscas tu ***librería.gem*** y lo pasas a la PC sin conexión mediante una unidad **USB**, una ves en ella ejecuta la librería:

```
gem install -f --local *librería*.gem
```

Recuerda colocar la ruta completa de donde se encuentre el archivo .gem

Puedes encontran mas informacion en [esta pagina de ayuda](http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network) de Rubygems. [En inglés]

Con respecto a la pregunta de los lenguajes de programación, si me preguntas personalmente elegiría sin lugar a dudas **Python**, es muy amigable para iniciarse, es simple, directo, es como el lego de la programación y tiene una gran comunidad.

Si manejas algo de inglés puedes hacerte este [test](http://www.bestprogramminglanguagefor.me/). Es completamente orientativo pero asi podras hacerte una idea.

Un saludo y suerte.